# ios mylocationbutton missing on google map

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift

I'm trying to make a slide out navigation app with different views. One such view is the google map. However, when I run the app, the "Google" watermark appears but "My location" button is **missing**. It's very similar to this post [google map sdk ios 7 mylocationbutton disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908352/google-map-sdk-ios-7-mylocationbutton-disappear) but the `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;` doesn't change anything except give extra blank spaces. Also, it doesn't make sense why the google watermark appears and not the location button.

In `ViewController.swift`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    mapView.delegate = self

    mapView.settings.rotateGestures = false;
    mapView.settings.compassButton = true;

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {

        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, the location button was always on the view but the constraints on the map view wasn't set properly so it was not visible.

Answer (score 3):

The location button shows when `mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true` is called.

So, you should probably put

`mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
 mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true`

in the `viewDidLoad()` function.

Comment: Great! It fixed my problem! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a map inside a `UINavigationController` `ViewController`, navigation bar wasn't translucent and button didn't appear.

I set it to translucent and it showed up. No idea why but I hope that might help.

Of course don't forget to set

```
mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
```